# firebreath and visual studion 2015

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, atl, firebreath

I'm trying to build the basic firebreath (1.7) on visual studio community (2015).  The compiler is found but the ATL/MFC headers and libraries not.

I've then installed the WDK https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/hardware/dn913721.aspx, but still it fails:

CMAKE parameters:

```
D:\firebreath\Tutorialtestplugin\build>cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 Win64" -DFB_PROJECTS_DIR="D:\firebreath\Tutorialtestplugin"  "D:\firebreath\Tutorialtestplugin\firebreath"
```

Error:

> CMake Error at cmake/Win.cmake:126 (message):
>     FireBreath on windows requires ATL/MFC libs to be installed.  Please
>     download the Microsoft DDK and install the build environments in C:\WinDDK
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     cmake/common.cmake:31 (include)
>     CMakeLists.txt:41 (include)

Comment: Did you use the custom install and selected the MFC/ATL Option?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the Win 8.1 or 10 WDK include ATL headers/libraries.
The Win 7 WDK come with these files. Please search "atlwin.h" and "atls.lib" in your WDK installed folder to verify.

If these files are found, the problem is easy.
The cmake/Win.cmake will search following path to locate ATL headers and libraries:

> - $ENV{DDK_PATH}
> - $ENV{SystemDrive}/WinDDK
> - $ENV{ProgramFiles}/WinDDK
> - $ENV{CommonProgramFiles}/WinDDK

If your WDK are not installed in these folder. Cmake will not able to find them and print this error.

You can set environment variable "DDK_PATH" or use mklink.exe to create a folder link to the WDK installed folder. For example "mklink.exe /j %SystemDrive%\WinDDK your_WDK_installed_folder"